# Show different color of drag and drop highlight when mouse is over or between items

Tags: qt, pyside, pyside2

In my `ProxyStyle` class, I have a `drawPrimitive` function where I check if `element == QtWidgets.QStyle.PE_IndicatorItemViewItemDrop` to draw a green line when the user drag and drop items in my `TreeView`.

I set the action so that the item can be drop between but not over. So I would like to change the color of the highlight like this: 
1- line between item green (horizontal line)
2- line over item red (this line wraps the item).

Do you have an idea of how to do it? My `drawPrimitive` function have these arguments:

```
element(str)
option (QtGui.QStyleOptionViewItem)
painter(QtGui.QPainter)
widget (QtWidgets.QWidget)
```

Is there a flag like `PE_IndicatorItemViewItemDrop` that indicate if an item will be drop between or over?

Comment: Is the widget already showing the highlight and you just want to change the color?

Comment: yes, everything works except the color doesn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the latest in Qt's 5.11 branch on [github](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/33fea7e7a9155632f7ac3804a1a6d1d35324b6d0/src/widgets/styles/qcommonstyle.cpp#L684-L690), the test is a simple height equals 0:

```
case PE_IndicatorItemViewItemDrop: {
    QRect rect = opt->rect;
    if (opt->rect.height() == 0)
        p->drawLine(rect.topLeft(), rect.topRight());
    else
        p->drawRect(rect);
    break; }
```

Your code should use the same test to decide which color to use. If `option.rect.height == 0` then `Qt::green` else `Qt::red`.  Copy the current QPen and change its color, then call the base class' drawPrimitive.  The following pseudocode should suffice:

```
lastPen = painter.pen()
myPen = QtGui.QPen(lastPen)
if (option.rect.height() == 0):
    myPen.setColor(Qt.green)
else:
    myPen.setColor(Qt.red)
painter.setPen(myPen)
QProxyStyle.drawPrimitive(self, element, option, painter, widget)
painter.setPen(pen)
```

Sorry if the code is ugly. I don't know PySide, just C++ Qt.